# Woocommerce get cart item meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a 'Custom field' on my product page that I want to add above the title of a product in a Woocommerce cart page.

This is the custom field data:

[image]

I got it to work on a single product card with this PHP code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'product_card_beschrijving', 2);
 function product_card_beschrijving(){
    global $product;
    $beschrijving = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'product_card_beschrijving', true ); 
    if ( ! empty( $beschrijving ) ) {
        echo '<span class="beschrijving">' . $beschrijving . '</span>';
    }
 }
```

I've tried this same code for the cart page but altered it a little as such but the meta data of the custom field isn't being loaded. I've used `$get_item_data` and more but can't get it to work

```
<p class="cart-subtitel">
    <?php $beschrijving = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'product_card_beschrijving', true ); echo '<span class="beschrijving">' . $beschrijving . '</span>'?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is adapted from my Subtitle plugin/WooCommerce bridge [plugin](https://github.com/helgatheviking/kia-subtitle-woocommerce-bridge/blob/master/kia-subtitle-woocommerce-bridge.php#L45-L52)

```
/**
 * Cart product title.
 *
 * @param string $title - The product title.
 * @param array  $cart_item - The array of cart item product data.
 * @return string
 */
function kia_add_subtitle_to_cart_product( $title, $cart_item ){
    $_product = $cart_item['data'];
    $meta     = $_product->get_meta( 'product_card_beschrijving', true );
    if( $meta ) {
        $title .= '<span class="meta">' . $meta . '</span>';
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'kia_add_subtitle_to_cart_product', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This worked a charm! Thanks so much for your help! I used `$_product->get_meta` in my code and it was exactly what I was looking for!