# How to get meta value of the product in cart?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I have my own product meta field, I need to show its value in the cart(custom things).
I know that instead of $product->get_meta( '_opt_price', true ) in the cart I have to use $cart_item['data']->get_meta( '_opt_price', true ), but it doesn't work too.

I compared with another existed default meta field with type "number"(as mine) - with _stock.
$cart_item['data']->get_meta( '_stock', true ) doesn't work too.
What is the right way to show product meta field value, if the product is in the cart?

Comment: Did you try this solution yet? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58676462/4177565

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work with _stock or _opt_price, works only with $meta     = $_product->get_price(), I dont know why it doesn't see exactly meta

Comment: Check what get_meta_data() gives you; if it doesn't return anything, your $cart_item['data'] may not be something woocommerce knows what is; check its type with typeof and make sure it's a wc product.

Comment: Something in the cart can be not woocommerce item?

Comment: $cart_item seems to be an array. An array of what, one can only assume; if it's a representation of "the cart", one can also only assume. Or you can test it, so that you know. print_r and gettype help you with that.